# android map v2 marker onclick doesn't zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

I use a latlngbound to show mutli markers on the map v2. And when I click either one of the markers, I want the camera to zoom in.

```
        private void loadCenter(){

        Builder boundsBuilder  = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (int i=0;i<mmarker.saveMarker.size();i++)
        {
            boundsBuilder.include(mmarker.saveMarker.get(i));
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();

          map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 60));
}

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker mMarker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MARKER CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMarker.getPosition(), 15);

                map.animateCamera(zoom);
        return false;
    }
```

I use the on marker click listener to detect the click on the marker. The toast in the method works. But the camera just won't zoom in, do you know why? thank you!

Comment: what if you return true from onMarkerClick?

Comment: still the same result. Because the toast does work.

Comment: Are you sure 15 is the correct value? I mean, which value are you using when is not zoomed?

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mk.getPosition(), level));
            }
        }, 300);
```

I was implementing something similar and came across the same problem and noticed that the api has some problems with timming the request. this worked for me.

Comment: This was the solution. It looks like a delay IS required when hitting map markers in order for a map move and zoom to work properly. Note also that this post is correct in that you do not need to force this to get Looper.getMainLooper() as it will run just fine without it.

Comment: A delay is never a good solution ... I posted the correct answer below.

Answer (score 4):

When implementing `onMarkerClickListener` if you want to animate the camera by yourself you need to make `onMarkerClick` return `true`. If `onMarkerClick` returns `true` it will not execute the default action which is display the info window and pan the marker on the center of the screen.

Your code will be :

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker mMarker) {
        //Custom onMarkerClick actions here
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMarker.getPosition(), 15)));
```

Use this. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your method anywhere the map is ready, using:

`myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);`

after that you can simply use:

```
myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 15));
```

For me is working just fine.